# Get second number in a javascript calculator like app

Tags: javascript, input

I would like to store an input value to a variable.

I have an event listener to all buttons shown in html document and to the input field.

I test if the string value of the input is a number, then I store this value in prevNum and show it in input field.

Then I check if the clicked element is + , - , / , x , and save this val in operator variable.

Now I would like to get the next input value and store it in currentNum variable, but this is where I got stuck. I would like that, in input field the value shown is still prevNum val and after press on '+' or '-' or '/' or 'x' , the val is stored in operator (until here it works), but then I would like to store the input field value if its a number in currentNum. I don't know how to do that. How to ignore what is shown in inputField and get the value that is pressed after the operator.

```js
let inputField = document.querySelector('.input-filed');

let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');

let prevNum, currentNum, operator;

elements.forEach((element) =>
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (/^\d+$/.test(element.value)) {
      // checks if string is number
      inputField.value += element.value;
      prevNum = inputField.value;
    } else if (element.value === 'C') {
      inputField.value = '';
    } else if (
      element.value === '+' ||
      element.value === '-' ||
      element.value === 'x' ||
      element.value === '/'
    ) {
      operator = element.value;

      console.log('prevNUm ' + prevNum);
      console.log('operator ' + operator);
      console.log('currentNUm ' + currentNum);
    } else if (element.value === '=') {
      if (operator === '+') {
        console.log('+');
      }
    }
  })
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="title">Simple Calculator</h1>
    <div class="container">

        <input type="text" class="input-filed" placeholder="select number"/>

        <div class="sib"> 

            <div class="buttons">
                <div>
                    <button class="element special" value="C">C</button>
                    <button class="element special" value="+/-">+/-</button>
                    <button class="element special" value="%">%</button>
                </div>

                <div> 
                    <button class="element number" value="7">7</button>
                    <button class="element number" value="8">8</button>
                    <button class="element number" value="9">9</button>
                </div>

                <div> 
                    <button class="element number" value="4">4</button>
                    <button class="element number" value="5">5</button>
                    <button class="element number" value="6">6</button>
                </div>

                <div> 
                    <button class="element number" value="1">1</button>
                    <button class="element number" value="2">2</button>
                    <button class="element number" value="3">3</button>
                </div>

                <div class="element-two-wrap">
                    <button class="element expand-zero">0</button>
                    <button class="element">.</button>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="operation-buttons">
                <button class="element operation-element" value="/">÷</button>
                <button class="element operation-element" value="x">x</button>
                <button class="element operation-element" value="-">-</button>
                <button class="element operation-element" value="+">+</button>
                <button class="element operation-element" value="=">=</button>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got an idea. What if I add the numbers in an array and then I can get the vals from it ? I will try that

Comment: At your line `inputField.value += element.value;` you need to check if `operator` is set and then handle the new number input appropriately.

Comment: But at that time, why it mathers if operator has a value ?

Comment: because it indicates that an operator has been assigned and that any further numbers should be treated as `currentNum` instead of `prevNum`

Comment: Maybe I got it wrong, but if I do that where its says inputField.value += element.value; is too early and prevNUm is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add one if condition inside your 2nd else if condition for checking if prevNum exist then assign inputField.value to currentNum variable and then make inputField.value to ''. I guess this will resolve your issue.

```
else if(element.value === '+' || element.value === '-' || 
    element.value === 'x' || element.value === '/' ) {
    if (typeof prevNum !== 'undefined' && prevNum) {
         currentNum = inputField.value;
         inpurField.value = '';
    }
    operator = element.value;
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but currentNum will have same val as prevNum.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ended up using an array instead of 2 numbers and worked with last 2 values from array. Instead of pushing into array element.value, I pushed inputField.value, so decimal points numbers can be added too, to Array.
Thank you all for you answers.